# openmp tasks in nested loops

Tags: c++, loops, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to write the following piece of code.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
 int .... some variables
 for (int x:map){
 int ...
 #pragma omp single
 {
  #pragma omp task firstprivate(x,..) depend(out:a)
{
   assigning the variables some values
  }
  for (int loop over j)
  {
    #pragma omp task firstprivate(j) depend (in:a) depend (out:b)
{
    }
   third loop over k
    #pragma omp task depend(in:a,b)
   {
  
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Is this valid? The threads are getting formed but they are not getting into either (the loop over j i.e. the second loop) or the 3rd loop (I checked by print statements).

Please suggest how to correct this.

I tried printing inside the 2 loops and saw that nothing is getting printed which implies the threads don't enter into the loops at all. I was expecting that the work would be distributed among the threads but unfortunately I am unable to achieve this.

Minimum reproducible example:
(as asked in the comments I am making an example)

```
int a,b;
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp single
{for (int &x:map)
{
#pragma omp task
for(int i=0;i<x.second;++i)
{
vector<int> val = m2[i];
for (int j=0;j<val.size();++j)
{
#pragma omp critical
update a global map m3.
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: 1. `#pragma omp task firstprivate(x,..){` that brace needs to go on the next line.
2. `assigning the variables some values` it looks like that line is inside a task, so the variables need to be shared. However, you can not dictate in what order tasks are executed, so may that `assigning` should not be in a task *at all*.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I had added depend(out:a) and depend(in : b) to the tasks to indicate the order. Also, I did put the braces correctly while executing since this is pseudocode, I didn't put much emphasis on these details

Comment: You should move `#pragma omp single` just below `#pragma omp parallel`. What do you mean by "threads are not getting into either loops"? Have you used the necessary compiler options ( `-fopenmp`)  to turn openmp on?` Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Sure, I am adding one. Yes, I have added the flag. I added print statements inside the inner loops seems like those are not printed.

Comment: When creating a minimal reproducible example, please also indicate if the missing printouts occur only in OpenMP code or in serial code as well.

Comment: I've added a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a minimal reproducible example. If I copy the code you provided to https://godbolt.org/, it should compile and reproduce the problem (e.g. the missing printout).